# Finding an interval of convergence for the bisection method, and finding number of iterates needed for desired accuracy.

Tags: calculus, numerical-methods, numerical-calculus

I was given the following problem:

---

Let $\alpha$ be the largest root of 
        $$
   f(x)\equiv e^{x}-x-2=0.
  $$
    Find and interval $[a,b]$ containing $\alpha$ for which the bisection method will      converge to $\alpha$. Then estimate the number of iterates needed to find $\alpha$      within an accuracy of $5\times 10^{-8}.$

---

In class we were told only to find $a,b$ such that $f(a)\cdot f(b)<0$, so I picked $a=1,b=2$. The following is my solution:

> Given $\varepsilon$ we want to find $n$ such that
>           $$
>    |a-c_{n}|\le\frac{1}{2^{n}}\left(b-a\right)<\varepsilon,
>   $$
>       which yields
>           $$
>    n> \log_{2}{\frac{1}{\varepsilon}(b-a)}.
>   $$
>       Picking $a=1,b=2$, we see that
>           \begin{alignat*}{2}
>    f(a)&=e3&&<0 \\
>    f(b)&=e^{2}-4&&>0.
>   \end{alignat*}
>   Given $\varepsilon=5\times10^{-8}$ and letting $a=1,b=2$, we get
>           \begin{alignat*}{2}
>     &&n                     &> \log_{2}\frac{1}{\varepsilon} \\ 
>    &\implies\quad  &&> -\log_{2}{\varepsilon}  \notag\\  
>    &\implies\quad  &&> -\log_{2}{5\times10^{-8}}\approx{24.2535}  \notag\\  
>    &\implies\quad  &n                     &\ge 25.
>   \end{alignat*}

How can I know whether this condition is sufficient for the convergence of the method?

Comment: Correction: $f(a)=e-3$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider
$$f(x)= e^{x}-x-2 \implies f'(x)=e^x-1 \implies f''(x)=e^x \quad > \,\, \forall x$$
The first derivative cancels at $x_*=0$ and the second derivative test shows that this is a minimum.

So, two roots : one is positive (you got it) and the second is negative.

Answer (score 0):

When you apply the bisection method to a continuous function over an interval $[a,b]$, such that $f(a) f(b) < 0$, you get, by construction, convergence to a solution of the equation $f(x)=0$. This is simply due to the fact that you construct a sequence of intervals $[a_n,b_n]$ that always contain a solution of the equation and such that $b_n-a_n \to 0$.